# Download via Ruby Net::Http blows up the file size

Tags: ruby, file, http, download

I am trying to download a file over Http using the Net::Http module. The
file I am trying to download is
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/softwar...
which is of size 25M.

When tried to download via Ruby using the code below, I see that in Ruby
-2.1.2p95 the size is blown up to approx 85M. Now when trying to untar
this archive using the zlib utils [ Gem::Package::TarReader.new(
Zlib::GzipReader.open(archive) ) do |tar| ] it fails complaining it is
not in gzip format.

But when I try the same code in Ruby-1.9.3p429 it works fine and I am
able to see a file of 25M downloaded and untarred successfully.

Any idea what is going wrong? Am I missing something?

Code to download the file:

```
def downloadCLIPackage(destination)

  uri =
URI.parse("http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/softwar...)
  filename = "/home/praveend/clidriver.tar.gz"

  http_object = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http_object.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  f = open(filename, 'wb')
  f.write(response.body)
  f.close()

  filename

end
```

Thanks

Praveen

Comment: This is happening because Net::HTTP is automatically decompressing the data when it sees that the data is of type gzip. https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/448c87008e1bc66a93b8f21eedea060f281874a4/lib/net/http/response.rb#L254

Thanks to @yorickpeterse on ruby irc channel who helped on this. 

But still this doesn't help me getting it working end to end. Any one knows how can I save this untarred content [it contains directories and I want to preserve the tree structure] onto disk and make use of it?

Thanks

Praveen

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, Net::HTTP in Ruby-2.1.2 decompresses the file automatically if it finds that the target to be in gzip format.

To avoid de-compress automatically....one will need to set the header Accept-encoding to identity.

Answer from 7stud to same question asked by me on Ruby forum: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/5342548#1153921

Thanks

Praveen